# using Ajax , dropdownlist and page validation

Tags: callback, arguments, postback

using Ajax I filled Country, State and city dropdownlist. On land change state is filled and on state change city is filled properly.
Then when I try to save page I face this :`Invalid postback or callback argument`.
Searched and found out that this is due to change in ddl.selectedvalu change from initial value that is assigned by asp.net.
Now my question is that how can I let asp.net know that the new ddl value is valid?
Thank you.

Comment: I have checked this code but it do not work: 'public class ListBoxNoEventValidation : ListBox
{
}'

Answer (score 0):

In many pages it is recommended to use EnableEventValidation="false", but I prefer not to use it.
Some say that use Render and add value to notify .Net like this:

```
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{

    ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation("ddlLanguages ", "English");

    ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation("ddlLanguages ", "Tamil");

    ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation("ddlLanguages ", "Hindi");

    base.Render(writer);

}
```

but how to use it? where to put it?
for a better understanding I put here a sample code including Database script :
[hesab20.com/DownLoad/Ajax.zip](http://hesab20.com/DownLoad/Ajax.zip)
in this sample Javascript is used to fill drop-down list . But when click button is executed and a post back occur, error happen.
Please help if you have experience with this.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the sample code and change the drop down lists , automatically the other is filled , meaning that list item text and value is completely changed. finally click button for a post back.
you must see that error happens:
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation ....
 and note : EnableEventValidation="true" 
Thanks